# How to change default automount options for USB devices to read-only?

Tags: automount, usb-drive

I'm trying to change the default mount options for USB drives. I want them to mount as read only so no files can be extracted from the host computer.

Any ideas on how I can do this (using 15.10)?

Comment: For **each** USB drive?

Comment: @A.B.: yes, for every USB drive.

Comment: Using an `udev`-rule.

Comment: Seems to be a funny thing. Read here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119853/107084